# Dynamic selectizeInput in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to allow the user to type the value in the selectizeInput to find what they are searching from a long list (thus avoiding the scrolling action). When the user deletes the default value "None" (in this example), they are kicked out of the input box where they have to go back and type what they are seeking. Is there a way to avoid this so the user can backspace "None" to delete it and search for a value without being pushed out of the box?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic selectInput"),
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
  menuItemOutput("menuitem")
)
),
dashboardBody(
selectizeInput("heir1","Heirarchy1",c("NONE",letters),selected="NONE"),
selectizeInput("heir2","Heirarchy2",c("NONE",letters),selected="NONE"),
selectizeInput("heir3","Heirarchy3",c("NONE",letters),selected="NONE")
 )
 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$menuitem <- renderMenu({
menuItem("Menu item", icon = icon("calendar"))
})

heirarchy<-c(letters)

observe({
hei1<-input$heir1
hei2<-input$heir2
hei3<-input$heir3

choice1<-c("NONE",setdiff(heirarchy,c(hei2,hei3)))
choice2<-c("NONE",setdiff(heirarchy,c(hei1,hei3)))
choice3<-c("NONE",setdiff(heirarchy,c(hei1,hei2)))

updateSelectizeInput(session,"heir1",choices=choice1,selected=hei1)
updateSelectizeInput(session,"heir2",choices=choice2,selected=hei2)
updateSelectizeInput(session,"heir3",choices=choice3,selected=hei3)

 })

 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of the [Selectize JS](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) plugins via the `options` argument to `selectizeInput()`.

Note only the first input is updated.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic selectInput"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItemOutput("menuitem")
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(

        selectizeInput("heir1","Heirarchy1",c("NONE",letters),selected="NONE",
                       # use this syntax to bring in selectize.js plugins :)
                       options = list(plugins = list('restore_on_backspace'))),

        selectizeInput("heir2","Heirarchy2",c("NONE",letters),selected="NONE"),
        selectizeInput("heir3","Heirarchy3",c("NONE",letters),selected="NONE")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$menuitem <- renderMenu({
        menuItem("Menu item", icon = icon("calendar"))
    })

    heirarchy<-c(letters)

    observe({

        hei1<-isolate(input$heir1) # don't allow re-evaluation as users type

        hei2<-input$heir2
        hei3<-input$heir3

        choice1<-c("NONE",setdiff(heirarchy,c(hei2,hei3)))
        choice2<-c("NONE",setdiff(heirarchy,c(hei1,hei3)))
        choice3<-c("NONE",setdiff(heirarchy,c(hei1,hei2)))

        updateSelectizeInput(session,"heir1",choices=choice1,selected=hei1)
        updateSelectizeInput(session,"heir2",choices=choice2,selected=hei2)
        updateSelectizeInput(session,"heir3",choices=choice3,selected=hei3)

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that `isolate()` is necessary to prevent `updateSelectizeeInput()` from being re-called and messing everything up as your users type.

EDIT:

Sorry mate, misread your desired behavior when I answered. I think you will get what you want if you remove the `options =`, but keep the `isolate()`.

```
selectizeInput("heir1","Heirarchy1",c("NONE",letters),selected="NONE")
```

It is the `updateSelectizeInput()` without `isolate()` that is causing the cursor to leave the input field and requiring your users to re-click after a deletion.

Let me know if that's not what you were describing. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Nate. The solutions requires the user to backspace multiple times (as many times as there are characters in the string plus one) to clear out a field. Is there a way to achieve this with one fluid motion (i.e. backspace clears out the entire field with one backspace before searching?) The only reason I ask is the strings will have 20+ characters in my real example, and it would be very time consuming to erase them individually.

Comment: Hey Eric, I think you can get that behavior by ignoring the `options` I originally suggested. I made an edit that I think matches your desired behavior, let me know if it works.

Comment: Nate, after investigating this further. I am realizing that it doesn't work all the time. At times the isolate prevents the updates from automatically occurring. For example on your demo, I can pick "a" for the first input and I can also "sometimes" pick '"a" for the second input. Any ideas on another approach that can guarantee results?

Comment: I see that behavior now. I'm not sure how to implement this, without having a priority order.  What would happen when a user selects "a" for input1 and input2 is already "a"

Comment: The user should not be allowed to select "a" until "a" is cleared out from an already assigned input and becomes available for selection.